# Windows Machine Cert File Mappings

Tags: windows, cryptography, vpn

**BLUF**

If you know a windows machine certificate file name, can you view the file contents in the windows certificate store?

**Background**

I am working with the Windows 7+ VPN Client. It does not let you directly select the certificate that should be used for a connection and provides very limited feedback. The most notorious error RRAC is 13801 that roughly sums up to 'I don't like something about a certificate being used, but i am not going to tell you what exactly'.

Using the Event Viewer to view Security entries, I do see that there is a request for a certificate. Something like:

```
 ProviderName Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider 
  AlgorithmName UNKNOWN 
  KeyName {#################} 
  KeyType %%2499 
  KeyFilePath C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\<filename>
  Operation %%2458 
  ReturnCode 0x0
```

I was wondering how i could use the filename mentioned above to view the certificate properties (IE: see that the one i want is being used). Right now my only method is to import a certificate via mmc and see the new file being created at the time of import. I cannot use this trick for certificates that are already imported on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the identifiers here are for the private key.  The private key doesn't know where the certificate lives, because the architecture is that the cert object / cert store know where the private key is for a given certificate.

To see the mapping between certs in a cert store and the keys on the system you can use `certutil -store`, e.g.:

```
C:\>certutil -store my
my
================ Certificate 0 ================
...
================ Certificate 7 ================
Serial Number: 3451b93c10f9279348a949f729d1ff10
Issuer: CN=localhost
 NotBefore: 1/26/2015 2:19 PM
 NotAfter: 1/25/2020 4:00 PM
Subject: CN=localhost
Signature matches Public Key
Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
Template:
Cert Hash(sha1): 15 e3 4c d3 2d a7 54 99 a9 17 8f 17 26 25 63 25 8f 3a 94 28
  Key Container = IIS Express Development Certificate Container
  Unique container name: fad662b360941f26a1193357aab3c12d_1fcb2e07-cec4-4ba1-9c78-58a431e1aefd
  Provider = Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Encryption test passed
CertUtil: -store command completed successfully.
```

Where the thing to match is `Key Container` in this output is the same as `KeyContainerName` in the event, and `Provider` in this output is `ProviderName` in the event.

You can also dump the user store (the default is the machine):

```
C:\>certutil -user -store -silent my
my
================ Certificate 0 ================
Serial Number: 0123456789abcdef
Issuer: E=issueremail@example.org, CN=cn.issuer.example.org, OU=ExampleOU, O=ExampleO, L=Locality, S=State, C=Country
 NotBefore: 11/12/2013 6:15 AM
 NotAfter: 12/13/2014 7:16 AM
Subject: E=subjectemail@example.org, CN=cn.subject.example.org, OU=ExampleOU, O=ExampleO, L=Locality, S=State, C=Country
Non-root Certificate
Template:
Cert Hash(sha1): ff 3d 35 54 54 fd ff ea 52 cd 71 6f e7 14 24 75 3f f7 fe cf
  Key Container = {F76693EF-BDC3-4AEC-855A-3A2F65EB9C14}
  Unique container name: 0148994a057f4e05acb6407550cdde40_1fcb2e07-cec4-4ba1-9c78-58a431e1aefd
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
Private key is NOT exportable
Encryption test passed

...
================ Certificate 51 ================
Serial Number: 0123456789abcdef
Issuer: E=issueremail@example.org, CN=cn.issuer.example.org, OU=ExampleOU, O=ExampleO, L=Locality, S=State, C=Country
 NotBefore: 11/12/2013 6:15 AM
 NotAfter: 12/13/2014 7:16 AM
Subject: E=subjectemail@example.org, L=Locality, S=State, C=Country
Non-root Certificate
Template:
Cert Hash(sha1): 2a 81 f8 d1 c7 40 13 2f 15 5a 5e 30 41 1a 2b 13 71 93 db 9e
  Key Container = {2572D484-D352-4B32-BB00-236B755B7F81}
  Unique container name: b11d717c1718a3bc6ad1769f2226998e_1fcb2e07-cec4-4ba1-9c78-58a431e1aefd
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
Private key is NOT exportable
Encryption test passed
```

In addition to the `-user` switch I specified `-silent`, because I have some smartcard backed certificates and I didn't want to deal with getting prompted for the card and PIN.

Comment: Yup, that provides that mapping i need. Thank you!